# Why would a shallow well pump go on and off too much?

Tags: plumbing

Shallow well pump pressure goes up to 50, then pump shuts off, even though the tap is still on. With a small, I think 2 gallon, pressure tank, usually the pump stays on until you turn off the tap. Water pressure seems fine, but the pump is going on and off too much.

Answer (score 2):

Your pressure tank is what is considered "water-logged". If it is a bladder tank, the bladder inside the tank may need to be re-pressurized or perhaps the bladder tank needs to be replaced. There is an air valve on top to do this, if it only needs re-pressurizing.

To my recollection, and I may be wrong, and possibly your specs may differ, the tank, with no water in it, and the pump turned off, should have about 7 PSI of pressure in the bladder. You may need to drain the water lines in the house to do this. When the tank is then working with the system and the pump increases the pressure to 40 PSI+, then the pump should cycle as it used to.

Comment: Non-bladder tanks, (air accumulator, floating disc separator), drain until the tank is empty of nothing but air. If there's an air-charge Shrader valve on the manifold, you can use compressed air to hurry the process. Depending on water use, non-bladder tanks need to be recharged with air every 3-6 months as the air diffuses into the water and slowly gets removed. Bladder tanks that have a perforated bladder will hold no pressure when the tank is empty, replace. Bladder air pressure will be 5-20psi depending on manufacturer, is usually posted on a ring escutcheon around the Shrader valve.